# Create a background proccess that terminates a program on KeyPress (VB 2013)

Tags: vb.net

I'm look for code which can help me accomplish what the title suggests.

I want this because I have an issue with a program which is quite buggy (it's a game), and if It freezes, and results in a black screen. Even after using Shift+Ctrl+Esc, Ctrl+Alt+Del, Alt+F4 and the rest of them, I acn't seem to end the program. So I thought that a KeyPress event would work, as it doesn't require me to use the UI in any way.

However, I've never used VB for anything other than Form's, so I have no idea how to start on something which runs in the background.

Thanks :)

Comment: My suggestion is to run the game inside a virtual machine

Comment: Do you deem that being simpler than creating a small process that runs at start-up and doesn't require any additional actions?

Comment: The answer below is correct. If the game makes ctrl alt delete stop working, there is not hack to fix it. You either need to solve the cause of the crash or prevent the crash from taking out windows; this is why I suggested a vm

Comment: It doesn't. I just can't see the overlay.

Comment: This might be the direction you are really looking to go: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18638/Using-Window-Messages-to-Implement-Global-System-H

Comment: I have no idea how to create anything using C++

Answer (score 1):

A background app won't help in this case.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> is specail key combo that is handled directly by Windows and can't be intercepted by a running program.

What this means is that if your game locks up and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> doesn't bring up the Windows menu, then the game has corrupted the system. The only fix at that point would be a restart.

---

That being said, you can kill a running process using VB.NET like this:

```
For Each program As Process In System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcesses
    If program.ProcessName = "ProcessName" Then
            program.Kill()
    End If
Next
```

Read more about it on the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1f3ys1f9(v=vs.110).aspx).

---

Okay, so Windows isn't actually locking up, but you just need some way to kill the process. Use the above code, replacing "ProcessName" with the name of your game process, and then either:

1. (basic) Turn the VB.NET code into an .exe file. Then set up a keyboard macro (using your keyboard software or some freeware) to launch the .exe you made which will kill all running instances of the given process. or...
2. (advanced) Import "user32.dll" into the VB.NET code, call `SetWindowsHookEx` with a hook id of 13, a pointer to a `LowLevelKeyboardProc` function, the handle to your running program, and a thread id of 0. Then, whenever a key is pressed in any program, your KeyboardProc function will be invoked. If the key(s) pressed match your desired kill-key combo, then run the above process killing code. [This](http://vbnet.mvps.org/index.html?code/hooks/setwindowshookex.htm) looks like it may give you more step-by-step instructions.

Comment: What if it's a key combination not exclusively used by Windows, such as Ctrl+* or something similar?

Comment: If Windows isn't pumping messages (meaning, responding to key presses), then nothing will be.

Comment: It does respond but it doesn't change from a black screen to facilitate the change in form. For example, I can hit Ctrl+Alt+Del and I can mouse over each option, and click them but I cannot see what I'm clicking. That's the problem.

Comment: And how do you know the procces manager shows up if you can't see a thing?

Comment: The Mouse cursor changes from the arrow to the hand, and when I hit esc to close the Ctrl+Alt+Del screen, the arrow turns to the loading symbol for a millisecond.

Comment: I have this which is pretty much the same, but it's focused on a textbox_KeyPress event.

Comment: I've updated the answer to give you two ways to run the "process killing" code

Comment: For step 1, I guess it would be useful to set the program to close after it has terminated the program, so I don't have to close it myself. Also, I'm guessing this would only work once until close.